# Ban IP Address From Constantly Hitting My C# / Azure Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service

There is a plug-in for WordPress (sorry, I forget the name) which allows me to automatically ban or throttle an IP address if they are accessing pages too quickly, such as 1 page per second.

I have a problem on a C# website I have written hosted on Azure because someone in France is slamming my site every 1 second.  It's been going on a couple of weeks and it's getting a tad annoying.

Is there something very simple available for C# or Azure which is equivalent to the WordPress plug-in which allows me to automatically ban or throttle an IP Address?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure to block requests from IP addresses when the total number of requests observed within the time window defined by **requestIntervalInMilliseconds** exceeds the value set in the **maxRequests** attribute.

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <dynamicIpSecurity>
        <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="10" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="1000"/>
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Comment: Thank you kienct89. This is an excellent solution and very easy to implement. Now to figure out how to not block search bots. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks, but for me not work, after add security section in webconfig  site write error 500